# How to allocate memory to an array of void function pointers and assign adresses to the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I want to create an array of void function pointers, allocate its memory and assign to the array adresses of function I want it to contain. 
While declaring an array, you are able to assign to it elements in a form of list in brackets like this:

```
const char *array[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS] = {"foo1", "boo2", "foo2", "boo2"}; // etc.
```

Alright. I have declared an array of pointers to void functions as it is shown below:

```
void (*pointerArray)(void) = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof(*pointerArray));
```

My question is: **Is it possible to first declare a function and simultaneously allocate its memory, and then use "bracket form" of assigning adresses on my pointerArray so it actually points to any function?** More general question: Is there any way to do it quick way or I have to do this the long way as shown here:

```
pointerArray[0] = func1;
pointerArray[1] = func2;
pointerArray[2] = func3; // etc.
```

Comment: With C you have to do it "the long way", there's no way of initializing memory when allocating it dynamically (except to zero with the `calloc` function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `NUM_OF_ELEMENTS` being a constant value, there doesn't seem to be any good reason for you to allocate this array dynamically, so you may as well allocate it statically and initialize it upon declaration:

```
typedef void(*func_ptr)(void);
func_ptr func_ptr_array[] = {func1,func2,func3};
```

Comment: Now when I think about it, allocating memory dynamically for an array which containes a fixed amount of pointers and is not changed anywhere in a code doesn't make any sense... I'm so dumb, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Blackstar: I don't think it's a dumb question. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stack:

```
void (*p_stack[])(void) = { func1 , func2 } ;
```

Or in the case you really need to use malloc, first allocate your array with malloc and the another one on the stack and copy:

```
void (*p_stack[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS])(void) = { func1 , func2 } ;
void (**pointerArray)(void) = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof(*pointerArray));
memcpy( pointerArray , p_stack , sizeof( p_stack) ) ;
```

The initialization is done on the p_stack array, and is then copied to the allocated array.

Answer (score -1):

`void (*pointerArray)(void)` is a declaration of a function pointer. `*pointerArray` is a *function*. Functions don't have sizes and you cannot allocate them and there is no such thing as an array of functions and you cannot assign or copy functions.

What you need is an array of function pointers. To make things easier let's notate it with a typedef:

```
typedef void vfun(void);
typedef vfun* vfunp;

vfunp* pointerArray = malloc (NUM_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof(vfunp));

pointerArray[0] = func1;
pointerArray[1] = func2;
pointerArray[2] = func3; // etc.
```

Or you can have a statically allocated array if you want:

```
vfunp pointerArray[] = { func1, func2, func3 };
```

Comment: While using a malloc,`(*pointerArray)(void)` becomes an array when I'm allocating NUM_OF_ELEMENTS blocks each of size `sizeof(*pointerArray)`. Otherwise I could just write `void (*pointerArray[NUM_OF_ELEMENTS])(void);`. By the way, doesn't storing pointers to functions in an array take some memory space? I feel green about that to be honest.

Comment: Frankly I have no idea what you are talking about. Let's try again: `void (*pointerArray)(void)` is a *pointer to a function*. A pointer to something can point to the first element of an array of that something. So you would want to make `pointerArray` to point to an array of functions, but there are no arrays of functions, with malloc or otherwise.